# Cannot not restart a docker container with existing mounted host directory

Tags: docker, kitematic

I pulled a nginx+php container (https://hub.docker.com/r/imagine10255/centos6-lnmp-php56/) and had started that, it will create a folder to specific location i.e.(D:\xampp\htdocs\centos6-lnmp-php56\home\website), but now i can't restart it, anyone know how to do restart it with out deleting the folder above ?

error message is here:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container centos6-lnmp-php56: error while creating mount source path '/c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/centos6-lnmp-php56/home/website': mkdir /c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/centos6-lnmp-php56: file exists
```

command tried:

```
$ docker restart centos6-lnmp-php56
```

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container
>   centos6-lnmp-php56: error while creating mount source path
>   '/c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/centos6-lnmp-php56/home/website':
>   mkdir /c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/centos6-lnmp-php56: file
>   exists

As same as mysql container:
`$ docker restart mysql`

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container mysql: error
>   while creating mount source path
>   '/c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/mysql/var/lib/mysql': mkdir
>   /c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/mysql: file exists

Comment: could you please share the command that you are using to run the container?

Comment: docker restart centos6-lnmp-php56, the volume is mounted to D:\xampp\htdocs\centos6-lnmp-php56\home\website

Comment: as same as mysql container, i can't start every container with volume which is already mounted to host

Comment: When you get this error message? what is the command you are running?

Comment: could you please share the command that you ran to setup the containers. You mentioned that the mount point is at D:\ however, the container is trying to write at C:

Comment: could you please share the output of docker container inspect centos6-lnmp-php56

Comment: @debal i pulled and start the container in Kitematic, and create a sym link map c drive to d drive (/c/Users/hkveg/Documents/Kitematic/centos6-lnmp-php56/home/website->D:\xampp\htdocs\centos6-lnmp-php56\home\website)

Comment: It seems that the docker tool box has no permission to access d dirve